# R programming, export CSV with Sys.Date in title

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe in R and I want to export as CSV, with the Sys.Date() as the title of the CSV.

```
write.csv(MyDF, file="Sys.Date()")
```

seems not to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `paste(getwd(),"/",Sys.time(),".csv",sep="",collapse=NULL)` as your file path. Or if you just want the day and not the time, `paste(getwd(),"/",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep="",collapse=NULL)`.

Comment: `write.table(MyDF, file = paste(Sys.Date(), "csv", sep = "."))` would also work.